# Configure GA4 for a website with multiple locations

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on an eCommerce project for a company that will have a single site/domain but users are able to select their active location while shopping. This is a pretty common pattern for many sites where the user can order online or pickup in store.

I am trying to figure out the best configuration for GA4 to track both overall site traffic while also being able to traffic metrics for each individual location. I did find a resource [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9679158?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgeographically-distributed-ecommerce-retailer-selling-products-via-web-and-app) but it doesn't quite make sense. The summary of requirements are:

1. Ability to track GA4 metrics for the overall site
2. Ability to track GA4 metrics for each individual location (based on the location selected by a user)
3. Each individual location should be able to have access to view their own GA4 metrics.

The only solution I can think of that checks all 3 boxes is setting up a property for all analytics, as well as an individual property for each location and then send tracking events to both but this seems like bad practice. I would appreciate any insight or recommendations others might have for this scenario.

Comment: This is probably better suited to [webmasters.se]

Comment: I cross posted based on your recommendation. Thanks: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142586/configure-ga4-for-a-website-with-multiple-locations